# Computing i0 in the Butler-Volmer equation: How to interpret Wikipedia and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: electrochemistry

So far, when using the Butler-Volmer equation, I had `j0` given and could then just use `I = A * j0 * [exp(...) - exp(...)]`, with `A` the electrode surface area.

Now I have a material from which I don't know `j0` but just the rate constant. According to Wikipedia on [exchange current density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_current_density) I can compute `j0` as

[image]

Wolfram-Alpha on [Butler-Volmer equation](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ButlerVolmerEquationForElectrochemicalReaction/) however says:

[image]

In this equation, the expression `F * k0` would correspond to the above `j0`. `k0` is explicitly defined as the rate constant in `m/s` on that same page.

**Is Wolfram-Alpha wrong by missing out the concentration?** The `F * k0` does not even result in the units of a current density, and the whole expression will not evaluate as a current.

Comment: As I said before, Wolfram Alpha does not know apples from oranges when it comes to chemistry.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: So Wolfram Alpha is wrong and Wikipedia is right in that case, just to be sure?

Answer (score 1):

k0 has units of frequency (1/time)
All concentrations are surface concentrations (mol/area)

Sometimes people use k0 with units length/time and volume concentrations (mol/volume)

On Wikipedia: Coxy stands for Ox concentration * at equilibrium *. Cred stands for Red concentration * at equilibrium *. It's for 1 electron. Multiply by n for n electrons.

On Wolfram: [Ox] stands for Ox concentration at electrode, [Red] stands for Red concentration at the electrode. These concentrations are not necessarily at equilibrium.